# Can I see the option tar.gz in the GUI ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, nautilus, archive, compression

I am trying to zip in .tar.gz in the GUI, but only these options appear in the window: .zip,  tar.xz y .7z

[image: ventana]

Could the tar.gz be  in the window?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nautilus 7z compression](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1060082/nautilus-7z-compression) . The answer is no. They changed archival back-end to libarchive. But you can drop Nautilus and change it to Nemo or Caja.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments of the question: *The answer is no. They changed archival back-end to libarchive. But you can drop Nautilus and change it to Nemo or Caja.*

Another alternative is to simply open the arvchive manager and drag the files and/or directories you wish to compress to the window. You will then be prompted to create a new archive. The location of the archive will by default be in the directory of the added item(s) and you will have the list of compression formats available, like you are used to from 16.04.

Answer (score 1):

Simply, [install Nemo](https://askubuntu.com/a/294422/1460940) file manager. It has a lot of compression options including `tar.gz`.