# Ubuntu 18.04 - Enable advanced archive options like Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, archive, file-roller

Is there a way (for instance with a plugin or (gnome-) extension) to enabled advanced options for compressing files & folders in Ubuntu 18.04? Like the one that Ubuntu 16.04 had. This is what it looks like right now:

[image: Ubuntu 18.04 Screenshot for create archive]

And this is what it used to look like: 
(Note: This is not a 16.04 Screenshot. The option is still there if I compress an archive in file roller directly)

[image: File Roller Screenshot for new archive]

Now this very window popped up in 16.04 when I clicked right-click -> compress.

Is there any way to enable it in 18.04 that I can use it the same way (rightclick -> compress). I am completely aware that I can still do this if I open up file roller directly. But it would be much more convenient if I could do this directly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make nautilus use file-roller in 17.10 like in 17.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/969650/how-to-make-nautilus-use-file-roller-in-17-10-like-in-17-04), but I'll recommend to drop [this limited](https://askubuntu.com/a/1060095/66509)  Nautilus and use full-feature [Caja](https://askubuntu.com/a/1037305/66509) or Nemo instead.

Comment: @N0rbert Thank you! Nautilus-actions (or fma-config-tool in 18.04) worked perfectly fine!