# How to create .tar.gz from right-click compress menu in Gnome?

Tags: gnome, nautilus, 20.04

I am using the default Gnome desktop on Ubuntu 20.04. When I right-click on a file or folder and click on "Compress", I am given the option of .zip, .tar.xz, and .7z, but not .tar.gz (or any other archive formats). Is there a way I can enable .tar.gz in this menu?

Comment: Maybe it is time to drop Nautilus (as it had changed [the backend](https://askubuntu.com/a/1060095/66509)) and switch [to Caja](https://askubuntu.com/a/1037305/66509).